# Excluding abstractproperties from coverage reports

Tags: python, code-coverage, nosetests, abc, coverage.py

I have an abstract base class along the lines of:

```
class MyAbstractClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractproperty
    def myproperty(self): pass
```

But when I run nosetests (which coverage) on my project, it complains that the property def line is untested. It can't *actually* be tested (AFAIK) as instantiation of the abstract class will result in an exception being raised..

Are there any workarounds to this, or do I just have to accept < 100% test coverage?

Of course, I could remove the `ABCMeta` usage and simply have the base class raise `NotImpementedError`, but I prefer the former method.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There's no way to exclude the abstract properties precisely as you have it, but if you make a slight change, you can.  Have your abstract property raise an error:

```
@abstractproperty
def myproperty(self): 
    raise NotImplementedError
```

Then you can instruct coverage.py to ignore lines that raise NotImplementedError.  Create a .coveragerc file, and in it put:

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
    # Have to re-enable the standard pragma
    pragma: no cover

    # Don't complain if tests don't hit defensive assertion code:
    raise NotImplementedError
```

For more ideas about the kinds of lines you might want to always ignore, see: http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/config.html

Comment: I ended up finding out about `#pragma: no cover` on IRC and went with that inline. I'm not a fan of having an implementation in an abstract property (even if it's just `raise NotImplementedError` as it seems to defeat the purpose).

Comment: wait: you're ok with putting a "#pragma: no cover" comment on every abstract property, but you aren't ok with changing the body from pass to "raise NotImplementedError"?  To each his own, I guess...  Glad you found a solution you like.

Comment: I definitely agree it's not an optimal solution either, but I prefer using inline directives like that to altering the intended use and benefit of the abstract base class module..

Comment: Another option is to add a docstring to your abstract methods or properties, instead of using `pass`. This has the added benefit of having documentation for how your abstract methods / properties are expected to behave.

Comment: @WesleyBaugh: Sadly such commented empty methods are still reported by the coverage tool when you enable branch coverage (which should probably be enabled by default anyway).

Comment: @ereOn - The docstring solution worked fine for me, and I have branch coverage enabled. I'd say it's a bug if enabling branch coverage causes any changes to the behavior here given no branches are involved...

Comment: Note that the `exclude_lines` are regexes. [Here's the relevant doc section](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/7.2.1/excluding.html#advanced-exclusion)

Answer (score 70):

For me the best solution was what @Wesley mentioned in his comment to the accepted answer, specifically replacing 'pass' with a docstring for the abstract property, e.g.:

```
class MyAbstractClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractproperty
    def myproperty(self):
       """ this property is too abstract to understand. """
```

Answer (score 22):

I have custom skip logic in my `.coveragerc`:

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover
    @abstract
```

This way all abstractmethods and abstractproperties are marked as skipped.

Comment: Works well with tox !

Comment: One little snag... It's possible for an `@abstractmethod` to have an implementation that a child can call.  So, this could hide code that should be covered.  ([see note at the end of the documentation for abstractmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod))

Comment: If you use `import abc` instead of `from abc import abstract...`, and since these lines are regex, you can use `@abc\.abstract` to exclude all abstract methods/properties.

Comment: @TimTisdall but should it? In this case it's no longer abstract, even if that is possible I would consider it bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [docs](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/excluding.html). Add to your `pyproject.toml` the following section:

```yaml
[tool.coverage.report]
exclude_also = [
    "raise AssertionError",
    "raise NotImplementedError",
    "@(abc\\.)?abstractmethod",
    ]
```

or to `.coveragerc`

```yaml
[report]
exclude_also =
    raise AssertionError
    raise NotImplementedError
    @(abc\.)?abstractmethod
```