# how can i test an abstract method in python 2.6

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, abstract-class, python-2.6

I have an abstract class:

```
import abc


class Hello(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def add(self, foo):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def remove(self, foo):
        pass
```

I'm using abc for do abstract methods, so, when i do:

```
hello = Hello()
```

and this error is raised: `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Hello with abstract methods add, remove`

So I can test this type error with:

```
self.assertRaises(Exception, Hello)  # but this only test the constructor and i can't get the 100% of code coverage. I need call the add method and the remove method
```

Extra question: anybody knows how can i assert the message exception in python 2.6? (you can't use the `with:` for raise assertions.)

How can i test this abstract methods for get the 100% of code coverage?

Comment: Why are you trying to get code coverage on a method containing solely `pass`? Just make sure you have code coverage on any subclass of `Hello` that invokes `super(SubClass, self).remove()`

Comment: i want to get the 100% of code coverage, or do something like
""" start ignore code coverage """
def xxx():
    pass
""" end ignore code coverage """
if this is not posible, i want to get the coverage

Comment: If you're using the "coverage" package to do your coverage testing, you can [exclude code from coverage testing by adding a comment to it](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/excluding.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about creating a doc string of the abstract method instead of using `pass` as mentioned here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19275908/469992 ? It can also be used to give some information about what the method is supposed to do in the sub classes.

abstract.py,

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod                                            

class A(object):                                                                   
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta                                                        

    @abstractmethod                                                                
    def some_method(self):                                                         
        "This method should ..."                                                   

class B(A):                                                                        
    def some_method(self):                                                         
        return 1
```

test_abstract.py,

```
import unittest                                                                    
import abstract                                                                    

class TestB(unittest.TestCase):                                                    
    def test(self):                                                                
        self.assertEqual(abstract.B().some_method(), 1)
```

Then, using python 2.6.8, `nosetests --with-xcoverage` outputs,

```
.
Name       Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------
abstract       7      0   100%   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s
```

Answer (score 0):

What about checking the key in class dict:

```
>>> Hello.__dict__.has_key('__abstractmethods__')
True
>>> Hello.__dict__.has_key('__metaclass__')
True
>>>
```

You can make sure to overide all the method defined inside `Hello.__abstractmethods__` into your subclass.

```
>>> Hello.__abstractmethods__
frozenset(['add', 'remove'])
>>>
```

If you missed to re-defined any of those method in your sub-class, you will still getting TypeError for the missed methods:

`TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Abs_Hello with abstract methods remove`

OR how about testing like this :

```
 def check_all(abstract, sub_class):
    abs_method = abstract.__abstractmethods__
    for m in abs_method:
        if not isinstance(m, sub_class):
            raise TypeError("%s is not defined in subclass %s" % (m, repr(sub_class)))
```

Comment: these two properties are covered when i try to instantiate the class, but i need test the abstract methods (add and remove) for get the 100% code coverage.

Comment: In your sub-class, if you don't override both the method, you will get another TypeError for the missing method.

Comment: What are you trying to test, can you clear that part ?

Comment: i don't know how i should test an abstract class with abstract methods (i want to get the 100% of the code coverage), can anyone explain how to test my simple example class?

Answer (score 0):

You should never be instantiating an abstract class. The reason you are seeing that error is by design. Abstract methods are implemented in their sub-classes, because that defines the behavior where the classes are different. The abstract class encapsulates behavior that is shared between these sub-classes.

To illustrate, you want something like this:

```
class Language(Hello):

    def add(self, foo):
        self.baz.append(foo)

    def remove(self, foo):
        self.baz[foo] = None
```

Notice how `Language` inherits from `Hello`. 
So really you're supposed to test an instance of a sub class of your abstract class, not the abstract class itself.