# Why does python keep evaluating code after `pass`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found an interesting piece of code in python:

```
def x(cond):
    if cond:
        pass
        print('Still running!')

x(True)
```

I would expect this not to print anything, but it prints `Still running!`. What is happening here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886168/how-to-use-the-pass-statement-in-python

Comment: @Downvoters Why? I knew how the `pass` function worked (placeholder to say `I need an implementation!`), I just didn't know how this would work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per Python docs:

> `pass` is a null operation — when it is executed, nothing happens.

Source - https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass

As such, `pass` does not do anything and all statements after `pass` will still be executed.

Another way of thinking about this is that `pass` is equivalent to any dummy statement:

```
def x(cond):
    if cond:
        "dummy statement"
        print('Still running!')
```

Comment: Interesting, I thought that `pass` was a keyword placeholder.

Comment: I can see how the name is a bit confusing but thats where the docs help!

Comment: True, but since I thought that `pass` was a keyword I didn't look in the docs ;)

Answer (score 4):

pass does not mean "leave the function", it just means ... nothing. Think of it as a placeholder to say that you do not do anything there (for example if you do not have implemented something yet).
https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements

If you want to exit the function, you just `return` or `return None`

By the way other useful statements are `break` to exit the latest loop and `continue` to exit the current iteration of the loop and directly go to the next one.

Comment: Yep, I know about all those, I just saw this code and didn't know what it did (I very rarely use python).

Comment: Usually you have two reasons to use pass : you want to implement something in the future so you create the function and leave it empty, or the function is needed because of actions that might happen to an object you just create it but leave it empty because you have no use for it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass does nothing. When the program gets there, it says "ok skip this!".

Pass can be used to define functions ahead of time. For example,

```
def function_somebody_is_going_to_write_later():
    pass

def function_I_am_going_to_write_later():
    pass
```

That way you could write a file with functions that other people might work on later and you can still execute the file for now.

Comment: btw alternate method for defining functions is to simply add a docstring. in that case `pass` is not necessary.

Comment: Interesting. Is that available in Python 2.7?

Comment: yes. this is valid in all Python 2.x and 3.x. this trick btw is very useful when writing tests for abc classes: for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351626/how-can-i-test-an-abstract-method-in-python-2-6